# How to query rows as a group?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating an application that allow users to create "group profiles." A group profile represents one or more individuals. At the basic level, I'm using 2 tables: a parent table to group the profiles and a child table for the actual profiles. Assume that the profiles had age and gender details, how would I query the tables to get a list of parent table ids of:

- group profiles that represent just one profile?
- group profiles that represent a male and female between the ages of 25 and 30?
- group profiles that represent more than 2 profiles?
- etc.

At some point, I think I need to do a GROUP BY on the parent table id, but I'm a bit lost how to check the number of profiles a group profile has, how to meet certain criteria in the profiles (e.g. gender, etc.).

Here's a sample table with some data:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`foo_parent`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`foo_parent` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`foo_parent` (
  `foo_parent_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`foo_parent_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`foo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`foo` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`foo` (
  `foo_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `foo_parent_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` CHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `gender` ENUM('male','female') NOT NULL ,
  `age` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`foo_id`) ,
  INDEX `foo_foo_parent_id` (`foo_parent_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `foo_foo_parent_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`foo_parent_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`foo_parent` (`foo_parent_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`foo_parent`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`foo_parent` (`foo_parent_id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`foo_parent` (`foo_parent_id`) VALUES (2);

COMMIT;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`foo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`foo` (`foo_id`, `foo_parent_id`, `name`, `gender`, `age`) VALUES (1, 1, 'John Doe', 'male', 31);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`foo` (`foo_id`, `foo_parent_id`, `name`, `gender`, `age`) VALUES (2, 1, 'Jane Doe', 'female', 29);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`foo` (`foo_id`, `foo_parent_id`, `name`, `gender`, `age`) VALUES (3, 2, 'Billy Bob', 'male', 25);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`foo` (`foo_id`, `foo_parent_id`, `name`, `gender`, `age`) VALUES (4, 2, 'Suzie', 'female', 27);

COMMIT;
```

Sample queries and results:

Example 1: get all `foo_parent.id` where the profiles represented by the group profile includes a "male" and a "female" returns 1 and 2.

Example 2: get all `foo_parent.id` where the profiles represented by the group profile includes a "male" and a "female" and are between the ages of 20 and 30 returns 2.

**Also: if there is a blatantly obvious problem with this approach of grouping and querying profiles, please let me know.**

Comment: Could you clarify if there's a group profile in your request: `profiles that represent just one profile?` as well as the others? the word `profile`, for me... seems redundant, and I wouldn't know what to try to post.. Also, some expected data outputs would be a great addition to the table schemas you've already provided..

Comment: Hi Nonym, I meant "*group* profiles that represent just one profile." I edited the original post and added "group" for clarity.

Comment: are all foo profiles limited to 2 and only 2 unique foo_ids?  using [with rollup clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) you can solve the 1st example. in combination with having.  So with rollup on parent ID having count of male = 1 and female = 1

Comment: xQbert - a foo_parent can have 1 or more foo. So, it could be 1 or 2 or 3 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try building your predicate counts e.g. 'males between 20 and 30' or 'females  between 20 and 30' in an inline view and then referring to them in the where clause of the outer query. For example:

Example 1: get all foo_parent.id where the profiles represented by the group profile includes a "male" and a "female" returns 1 and 2:

```
select t.foo_parent_id
from
(
select fp.foo_parent_id,
sum(case when f.gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as males,
sum(case when f.gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as females,
sum(case when f.gender = 'Male' and f.age between 20 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as twenties_males,
sum(case when f.gender = 'Female' and f.age between 20 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as twenties_females
from foo_parent fp
left outer join foo f on f.foo_parent_id = fp.foo_parent_id
group by fp.foo_parent_id
) t
where t.males > 0 and t.females > 0;
```

Example 2: get all foo_parent.id where the profiles represented by the group profile includes a "male" and a "female" and are between the ages of 20 and 30 returns 2:

```
select t.foo_parent_id
from
(
select fp.foo_parent_id,
sum(case when f.gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as males,
sum(case when f.gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as females,
sum(case when f.gender = 'Male' and f.age between 20 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as twenties_males,
sum(case when f.gender = 'Female' and f.age between 20 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as twenties_females
from foo_parent fp
left outer join foo f on f.foo_parent_id = fp.foo_parent_id
group by fp.foo_parent_id
) t
where t.twenties_males > 0 and t.twenties_females > 0;
```

I've included the foo_parent table in these queries in case you want to include something like 'has no males or females between 20 and 40' or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create an alias for each of the sets of data you're querying (in this case gender) and then join to the same group as per the examples below:

```
select
  grp.foo_parent_id
from
  foo m
  ,foo f
  ,foo_parent grp
where
  m.foo_parent_id = grp.foo_parent_id
  and f.foo_parent_id = grp.foo_parent_id
  and m.gender = 'male'
  and f.gender = 'female'


select
  grp.foo_parent_id
from
  foo m
  ,foo f
  ,foo_parent grp
where
  m.foo_parent_id = grp.foo_parent_id
and f.foo_parent_id = grp.foo_parent_id
and m.gender = 'male'
and f.gender = 'female'
and m.age between 20 and 30
and f.age between 20 and 30
```

Answer (score -1):

For: **Example 1: get all foo_parent.id where the profiles represented by the group profile includes a "male" and a "female" returns 1 and 2.**

```
SELECT f.foo_parent_id
FROM (
    SELECT f.foo_parent_id, f.gender
    FROM mydb.foo AS f
    GROUP BY f.foo_parent_id, f.gender
) AS f
GROUP BY f.foo_parent_id
HAVING COUNT(f.foo_parent_id) >= 2;
```

For: **Example 2: get all foo_parent.id where the profiles represented by the group profile includes a "male" and a "female" and are between the ages of 20 and 30 returns 2.**

```
SELECT f.foo_parent_id
FROM (
    SELECT f.foo_parent_id, f.gender
    FROM mydb.foo AS f
    WHERE f.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30
    GROUP BY f.foo_parent_id, f.gender
) AS f
GROUP BY f.foo_parent_id
HAVING COUNT(f.foo_parent_id) >= 2;
```

I'm not sure this is the best approach, though.

For: **group profiles that represent more than 2 profiles?**

```
SELECT f.foo_parent_id
FROM mydb.foo AS f
GROUP BY f.foo_parent_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Comment: Read  comments in main question.  foo could have more than 2 entries. all of which could be male or female.  thus counting only will not work.

Comment: Which example are you referring to? For the first: If you're grouping using the gender as well, a count of the subquery will give you at least two records if there's a male and female. If there are only males, there will be one record for that foo parent id in the subquery. For the second: It's just as the first but includes an additional filter. For the third: As long as there are two profiles, return that foo parent id. Have you tried running the code? Or did I misunderstand the post somewhere?... Let me know..